# ClassNotFound when starting app

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to create an app for android wear but I get this error as soon as the app starts.

```
Process: com.demo.wear, PID: 20332
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.demo.wear/com.demo.wear.ui.WishesActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.demo.wear.ui.WishesActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.demo.wear-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.demo.wear.ui.WishesActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.demo.wear-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.demo.wear.ui.WishesActivity
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
        ... 14 more
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.demo.wear.ui.WishesActivity
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 13 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

I saw many questions about this topic but I cannot find a solution for it.

Here are the manifest and the gradle file in case needy.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.demo.wear"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.5.0'

    provided "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.4"

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
}
```

And the manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.demo.wear" >

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.demo.wear.ui.WishesActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here the related activity

```
package com.demo.wear.ui;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Asset;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataEvent;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataEventBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataMap;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataMapItem;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable;
import com.demo.wear.R;
import com.demo.wear.models.Wish;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;

public class WishesActivity extends Activity implements
        DataApi.DataListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, WearableListView.ClickListener {

    private static final String WISH_LIST_PATH = "/whishlist";
    private static final int RC_GOOGLE_API_CONNECTION_ERROR = 0;

    @InjectView(R.id.lstWishes_wishesActivity) WearableListView lstWishes;

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wishes);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        lstWishes.setAdapter(new WishesAdapter());
        lstWishes.setClickListener(WishesActivity.this);

        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Wearable.DataApi.removeListener(googleApiClient, this);
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RC_GOOGLE_API_CONNECTION_ERROR:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    if (!googleApiClient.isConnecting() && !googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                        googleApiClient.connect();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Wearable.DataApi.addListener(googleApiClient, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_GOOGLE_API_CONNECTION_ERROR);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                googleApiClient.connect();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error connecting with google API", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEventBuffer) {
        for (DataEvent dataEvent : dataEventBuffer) {
            if (dataEvent.getDataItem().getUri().getPath().equals(WISH_LIST_PATH)) {
                DataMap dataMap = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(dataEvent.getDataItem()).getDataMap();
                List<Wish> wishes = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataMap wishDataMap : dataMap.getDataMapArrayList("wishes")) {
                    Bitmap image = loadBitmapFromAsset(wishDataMap.getAsset("image"));
                    Wish wish = new Wish(wishDataMap.getString("name"), image);
                    wishes.add(wish);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public Bitmap loadBitmapFromAsset(Asset asset) {
        ConnectionResult result = googleApiClient.blockingConnect(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        if (!result.isSuccess()) {
            return null;
        }

        // convert asset into a file descriptor and block until it's ready
        InputStream assetInputStream = Wearable.DataApi.getFdForAsset(googleApiClient, asset).await().getInputStream();
        googleApiClient.disconnect();

        if (assetInputStream == null) {
            return null;
        }
        // decode the stream into a bitmap
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assetInputStream);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(WearableListView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        Wish wish = (Wish) viewHolder.itemView.getTag();

    }

    @Override
    public void onTopEmptyRegionClick() {

    }
}
```

Comment: I will add the class but it doesn't run even the first line on code :(

Comment: Compiler is looking for your class in the folder: "/data/app/com.demo.wear-1/base.apk". Are you sure, that it is deployed there?

Comment: Do you have to utilize the gradle.build file to import the class you need?  I ran into this problem a few days ago with a third party library I was trying to use.  What I did to resolve it was simply remove all the build.gradle stuff I added, and download the .jar file into my libs folder.  That seemed to work much better for me.  Then just make sure you're importing it.  I would consider this more of an "alternate" solution, rather than fixing what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @Tinki I guess it is an automated process. How can I be sure about that?

Comment: @dvsoukup I will try to remove butterknife and lombok. Of course I will keep the play services lib and the wereable support lib.

Comment: @dvsoukup nope, it didn't work :(

Comment: If you remove the library, you will also need to make sure you remove any reference to those classes in your code.
Did you try to get just the .jar files for each of those libraries and use that instead?

Comment: @dvsoukup Well the app is building correctly so there are no explicit references to those libs. Moreover, I invalidated the cache and clean the project before build, just to be sure. But still nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

One normal reason is that the package name in the `android:name`-property of the activity is wrong but as far as I see it is correct in your case, I also had a look at some of my own gradle-/manifest-files, both of your´s seem to be OK.

So I would recommend to try to clean the whole project and then completely rebuild it (assuming you are using Android Studio: Build->Clean Project and Build->Make Project). That´s what normally helps in my cases.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I already invalidate the cache and clean the project but... nothing, still the same problem.